# How to do only page segmentation / layout detection with Tesseract (mode --psm 2)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

I would like to use page segmentation from `Tesseract` without running the OCR, as I have my own custom OCR model, and it takes to long to run page segmentation AND OCR. I tried using the `--psm 2` mode in command line mode of `Tesseract`, and in `pytesseract`, and it didn't work as promised.

I'm working in Linux, and am coding in Python 3.10.

I currently use the `tesseract-ocr-api` from `layoutparser` [Documentation](https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/ocr.html?highlight=tesseract#tesseract-ocr-api). The code looks like the following:

```py
import layoutparser as lp
ocr_agent = lp.TesseractAgent()
res = ocr_agent.detect(img_path, return_response=True)
layout_info = res['data']
```

The `layout_info` then is a pd.DataFrame and contains Layout information on the level of blocks, paragraph, lines and words and also the OCR output. The problem is that this is very slow; on my machine it takes 7s per image and I actually don't need the OCR. Hence, I want page segmentation (also sometimes called layout detection) only.

According to the Tesseract ([Documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)), there is the  `--psm 2`mode "Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR". When I try this in the command line, this does not produce an output file (even if the output type is defined):

```
tesseract img.png outfile --psm 2
tesseract img.png outfile --psm 2 tsv
```

I also tried working with the python wrapper `pytesseract`, but it is quite slow and it again returns the pd.DataFrame with the layout AND OCR data, despite --psm 2 being specified:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
layout_info = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, config='tsv --psm 2', output_type='data.frame')
```

I'm using pytesseract==0.3.10 and tesseract 5.3.3-30-gea0b.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve page segmentation without OCR with Tesseract (or at least speed up the processing time of page segmenation + OCR?

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if -psm2 is implemented in your tesseract with the command:

```
tesseract --help-psm 2
```

Output on my machine:

```
Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

Gives you the Info:

`--psm 2`    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. **(not implemented)**

Therefore, if not implemented you can't use it.

Process time is related to the image quality and amount of text.
Have you a example, where ocr makes a time problem?

Comment: In the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md), there is no "not implemented". So, I'm not sure whether the help string or the md is more up to date. I assumed it's now implemented as some output is printed when one calls psm -2 (like "Estimating resolution as ...).

Comment: For example, a scanned book page with size 2481, 3508 and roughly 1300 words. It takes 7s on my machine with layoutparser.TesseractAgent() to perform ocr. And that doesn't scale if my use case is performing ocr on entire books.

Comment: @VeraBernhard, I have the windows installer, version 5.3.0 from [Uni Mannheim](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/). It said not implemented. I get also like "Estimating resolution as ..., but I think it doesn't do psm 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr?tab=readme-ov-file#orientation-and-script-detection-osd) - python wrapper of tesseract API. With it you can access also functionality not available via the tesseract executable (`pytesseract` just wraps tesseract executable without direct access to its API).

I did not test it, but with `tesserocr` you can use [AnalyseLayout](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/ea0b245c43ee850f1e571d469b313b90d58d8b13/src/api/baseapi.cpp#L798-L812) without running `Recognize` - see function documentation in the tesseract source code.

Tesseract process time depends also on your hw (e.g. ssd vs hdd, availability of SSE/AVX or NEON instruction).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried using it as follows:
```
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, PSM

with PyTessBaseAPI(psm=PSM.AUTO_OSD, path='/usr/share/tessdata/') as api:
    api.SetImageFile(img_path)
    api.Recognize()

    it = api.AnalyseLayout()
```
(I had to copy the tessdata manually into the '/usr/share/tessdata/' ). I don't get how to work with the `it`object. It always says `TypeError: 'tesserocr.PyPageIterator' object is not iterable`. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue what are you doing: when I run the example from tesserocr I got this result for `type(it)`: `tesserocr._tesserocr.PyPageIterator`... Have a look at the source code of tesserocr how to use the PyPageIterator https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/tesserocr.pyx#L380